# Saturation on characteristic curves of BJT

Tags: education

how come there is saturation region when \$V_{CE}<0.3 V\$?

[image]

I know that:

$$V_{CE}=V_{BE}-V_{BC}$$

thus I can decrease \$V_{CE}\$ also decreasing \$V_{BE}\$. In this case, when \$V_{BE}<0.7 V\$, the base-emitter junction is reverse biased and the base-collector junction remains reverse biased like in active mode. Maybe, if I impose the \$V_{BE}\$, the only way to decrease \$V_{CE}\$ is to increase \$V_{BC}\$?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In a BJT,
Forward active mode is when Emitter Base Junction (EBJ) is forward biased and the Collector based junction (CBJ) is reverese biased.
Saturation mode is when both Emitter Base Junction (EBJ) and the Collector based junction (CBJ) are forward biased.

When you plot the output characteristics ( Ic Vs VCE ) the constant looking region is when the part is in forward active mode.

Assuming that EBJ is forward biased, when you plot the output characteristics IC Vs VCB,  realize that the VCB(sat) is -0.5V for a typical BJT ....which would mean that the CBJ 
is also forward biased at this point.The difference between VCB and VCE is almost a constant VBE ( if EBJ is already forward biased ).
Then, the output characteristics of Ic Vs VCE is merely a shift of the curves in the positive direction by a factor of VBE=0.7V

Hence VCE(sat) = VCB(sat) + VBE =  -0.5V + 0.7V = 0.2V

Therefore when VCE is less than 0.2V ( 0.3V in your case ), the transistor will be operating in saturation region.

Points to remember: The biasing voltages are applied across Emiter-base and Collector-base

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about Soft Saturation (when the transistor can tolerate a B-C forward bias of 400 mV)?

Quoting directly from Behzad Razavi's book:

[image: Behzad Razavi - Section 4.5]

Answer (score 0):

The Base-Collector junction is normally reverse biased, so while using "- V<sub>BC</sub>" in the equation is technically correct, it may be confusing you. In an NPN transistor the Collector is normally the most positive terminal, followed by the Base and then the Emitter. However in the saturation region V<sub>CE</sub> falls below V<sub>BE</sub>, so the Base-Collector junction goes from being reverse biased to forward biased.

The Base-Emitter junction is always forward biased. In your graph the line at 0.7V is V<sub>CE</sub>, not V<sub>BE</sub> (V<sub>BE</sub> is not shown, but we can assume it is around 0.6~0.7V when Base current is set to a value above zero).

Comment: Hi @Bruce Abbott, my book said only that the saturation region occurs when \$V_{CE}< 0.3 V\$. Why you said that it occurs when \$V_{CE}\$ falls below \$V_{BE}\$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your graph shows saturation starting to occur below 0.7V. Due to differences in construction some transistors start to saturate at a lower voltage than others.